# React native unhandled promise rejection p0

Tags: react-native

Hello i get the above error when i run my project what am i doing wrong?

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import {
    Image,
    Platform,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Switch
} from 'react-native';
import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';
import {Linking , SMS }from 'expo';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'

class Sendsms extends Component {
    state = {switch1Value: false}

    toggleSwitch1 = (value) => {
        this.setState({switch1Value: value});
        console.log('Switch 1 is: ' + value);

    }

    askSMSPermissionsAsync = async () => {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.SMS);
    };
    HandlePress = () =>{
        console.log('try to send sms');

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>{this.state.switch1Value ? 'Switch is ON' : 'Switch is OFF'}</Text>
            <Switch onValueChange = {this.toggleSwitch1.bind(this)} value = {this.state.switch1Value}/>
        <Button title="sendSMS"  onPress={this.askSMSPermissionsAsync} />
        </View>
    )
    }
}
```

I tried rebulding project and deleting the build folder with no luck 
I also tried to copy the code in some other project still same error

```
export default Sendsms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `await` call in a `try/catch` to handle the rejected promise. I'm not sure why it's getting rejected but you could `console.log` to find out by doing:

```
  askSMSPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.SMS);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Remember that `await` is just syntactic sugar for a promise.

Comment: Check out the docs for expo permissions: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#api it should be `getAsync` instead of `askAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

`await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.SMS);` results into a Promise which might be rejected. When using promises, always use a `try {} catch(e) {}` to catch any rejections.
Check the logging for more info about the rejection.

So:

```
askSMSPermissionsAsync = async () => {
  try {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.SMS);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```